# Encoding utf-8 and decode to iso-8859-16

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

Im trying to understand how the transformation from utf-8 to other encodings work.

In this example:- I have a string that I encode with 'utf-8' and decode with 'iso-8859-16'.
Just trying to understand, how a extra byte is added during transformation?

```
>>> r_post='Hello Günter'
>>> r_post=r_post.encode('utf-8')
>>> r_post
b'Hello G\xc3\xbcnter'
>>> r_post=r_post.decode('iso-8859-16')
>>> r_post
'Hello GĂŒnter'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Hello G\xc3\xbcnter
```

This is a byte string, with the two bytes used for 'ü' conveniently highlighted. In the UTF-8 encoding, the character 'ü' is represented by the two bytes `C3 BC`.

Reading those bytes and interpreting them in the ISO-8859-16 encoding gives you the characters "Hello GĂŒnter". In 8859-16, the byte `C3` represents the character 'Ă' and `BC` represents the character 'Œ'.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) if you need a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation..Very helpful.